# multiple class inheritence with two separate kwargs

Tags: python, class, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

hey so what i wish to do:

in words - i want to create a class that inherits from two other classes, each with its own arguments. i want to call the constructor of the first parent (Foo) that gets the argument kwargs and in Foo creates an attribute config of itself, based on kwargs. after that, the constructor of Bar is called and takes as argument the config attribute created in the Foo constructor.

```
class FooBar(Foo, Bar):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FooBar, self).__init__(**kwargs).__init__(self.config)
#in theory this line should call the constructor of Foo, with kwargs as the init argument
#in Foo, use kwargs to assign an attribute named 'config' to the class
#such that after finishing, the constructor of Bar could be called and it's init argument would be #the config attribute assigned earlier to self


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.config = kwargs.get('config')

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.stuff = config.stuff
```

Comment: I would recommend to make a class which takes as arguments Foo and Bar... or just call them explicitly in the body of the constructor

Comment: See https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ for advice on using `super` properly, especially in `__init__`. The fact that both `Foo` and `Bar` have a parameter named `config` complicates this somewhat; are you able to modify their signatures? `Bar`, in particular, should probably take a `stuff` value directly, rather than extracting it from a `config` argument.